# FlexSlider - overlay content appears after animation

Tags: flexslider

I have a full-width FlexSlider with in every slide an image and some HTML content on top.

```
<li>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="box"></div>
</li>
```

But for some reason, the HTML content appears only after the slide animation.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39wPU/1/

I'm thinking it may have something to do with the overflow property on the div with class "flex-viewport". If you disable it, the problem goes away (but another one arises - i.e. having a very large horizontal overflow).

The problem returns whenever you place an overflow:hidden on any containing element.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: It seems the problem only occurs in Chrome. Safari and Firefox are fine.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your `.box` selector:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
```